# Why the alarm receiver is not trigger in android?

Tags: android, datetime, timer, broadcastreceiver, alarmmanager

I am implement a simple alarm function, which is used to trigger some function at the specific date time.

The problem is I have set the time already, but the receiver seems never called.

Here is how I implement:......

1) in manifest :

```
 <uses-permission android:name="com.android.alarm.permission.SET_ALARM" />
```

and

```
<receiver android:name=".Listener.AlarmReceiver" />
```

2) in the main activity (I would like to trigger on  *4th June 2014, 02:06 p.m.*)

```
profilePic.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
             GregorianCalendar date = new GregorianCalendar(2014,6,4,14,6);
             long dateTime = date.getTimeInMillis();
             Log.d("test1",date.toString());
             AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) ctx.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
             Intent intentAlarm = new Intent(ctx, AlarmReceiver.class);
             alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, dateTime, PendingIntent.getBroadcast(ctx, 1, intentAlarm, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT));
        }
    });
```

And I have also log the time

```
java.util.GregorianCalendar[time=1404453960000,areFieldsSet=true,lenient=true,zone=Asia/Hong_Kong,firstDayOfWeek=1,minimalDaysInFirstWeek=1,ERA=1,YEAR=2014,MONTH=6,WEEK_OF_YEAR=27,WEEK_OF_MONTH=1,DAY_OF_MONTH=4,DAY_OF_YEAR=185,DAY_OF_WEEK=6,DAY_OF_WEEK_IN_MONTH=1,AM_PM=1,HOUR=2,HOUR_OF_DAY=14,MINUTE=6,SECOND=0,MILLISECOND=0,ZONE_OFFSET=28800000,DST_OFFSET=0]
```

3) Receiver

```
public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Log.d("test1", "alarm");
        Toast.makeText(context, "Alarm Triggered", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

I waited until the 02:06p.m. but nothing happened, and receiver is not called. How to fix the problem? Also, is it possible to set more than one alarm, is it all I need to do is to create another datetime and fire the alarmManager.set() again, will it overwrite the old timer? Thanks for helping.

**Updated**

For the AlarmReceiver in the mainifest ,

I changed to

```
<receiver android:name="com.example.antismoke.Listener.AlarmReceiver" />
```

And the class is

```
package com.example.antismoke.Listener;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Log.d("test1", "alarm");
        Toast.makeText(context, "Alarm Triggered", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

so I think package name is not the root cause? Thanks for helping

Comment: are you using package name correctly?

Comment: .Listener.AlarmReceiver is a correct path

Comment: have a look on this http://stackoverflow.com/a/16119351

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using GregorianCalendar , try to use Calendar.
Try the following, it should work:

```
Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), AlarmReceiver.class); 
PendingIntent sender = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(AlarmSample.this, 0, i, 0);

Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hour); // set hour
calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minuite); // set minute
calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0); // set seconds     
AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE); 
am.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), sender);
```

Answer (score 1):

you should use package name correctly, if you have different package ,

receiver android:name="XXX.XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX.AlarmReceiver" />

check this out

Comment: I double checked it , the package name is correct. Thanks

Comment: is there more than one package ?

Answer (score 1):

1) You don't need this persmission (com.android.alarm.permission.SET_ALARM) to receive alarm.

2) Change this line:

```
<receiver android:name=".Listener.AlarmReceiver" />
```

to

```
<receiver android:name=".AlarmReceiver" />
```

Comment: 1) Is your Receiver declared inside Application section?

Comment: Try changing you dateTime to:
long dateTime = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() +  5 * 1000;

Alarm should fire in 5 seconds. If it's true, problem is in you date. Possibly Mobile phone clock is set not like you are expecting

Answer (score 0):

replace `alarmManager.set` with `alarmManager.setRepeating`

or try to use this:

```
public static AlarmManager am = null;
public static PendingIntent sender;
Intent intent1 = new Intent(ctx, Reciver.class);
sender = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(ctx, 1, intent1, 0);
am = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
long l = new Date().getTime();
am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, l, 1500, sender);
```

Comment: Thanks. I am afraid I am confused, if a particular time is set to alarm (eg. 2014/6/4 2:06 p.m.) why it is repeat alarm?

Comment: `setRepeating` will set a periodic alarm which is not what user wants.

Answer (score 0):

Ok , finally I figure out it is because the month start at 0 in GregorianCalendar. So June should use 5 instead of 6

I should have noticed the problem. Thanks for all you guys